# PHPUnit: dynamically loading different env files

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm working on a project (Laravel 6) with multiple developers.

We run PHPUnit regularly when developing, and we have the `.env.testing` and `phpunit.xml` files committed to the repo so that all developers have the same testing environment defined.

We are now looking at how we could run PHPUnit on our development server as a final check. However, because the `.env.testing` and `phpunit.xml` files are geared to run on our local machines, how can I tell PHPUnit on the development server to use a separate `.env` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see the point of committing `.env.testing`, since it in my opinion defeats the purpose of `.env` files (setting different environment variables depending on your server / OS etc.).

At the moment you are locking your developers / server into using this specific `.env` file, so what I would recommend doing instead is the following:

I would remove `.env.testing` from your repo, add a new `.env.testing.example` that has all the default values that you need to run it locally, this allows every developer to copy the file to `.env.testing` while still allowing specfic enviroment values to be set by each developer, this will also allow you to have a custom `.env.testing` file for your development server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remul. I was hoping to avoid that but it does makes sense and how we handle things with other environments.

Comment: Just as an additional suggestion on a detail here: Use the `.dist` suffix instead `.example`, this is more streamlined with phpunit itself which also has `phpunit.xml.dist` which you can put into the repository and every developer (user) of the project can create an override w/o the `.dist` extension. Make this visible in `.gitignore`, too.